# How to get package name from share preference?

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, package

I am working on appLocker in which I have to set the password on installed application of device.
for that I have created a list in which I am getting all the installed application. User can select the the application by using checkBox and set the password on that. for that I have to get the package name of that application. I am able to get the package name of selected application and save them using Share Preferences. now I have to get that package name in an another activity. please tell me how can I get that.

this is the code where I am getting the package name.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
        if (R.id.select_done_btn == v.getId()) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), MODE_PRIVATE);
            int[] indexes = appListAdapter.getSelectedItemIndexes();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; ++i) {
                AppInfo appInfo = installedApps.get(indexes[i]);
                sb.append(appInfo.getPackageName()).append(";");
            }
            Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("lock_apps", sb.toString());
            editor.commit();
```

and this the code section where I have to get that package name to lock the selected application in another activity..

```
public void run() {
        while (true) {
            Log.i("lock", "lockerThread run.");
            String packname = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
            if ("**PACKAGE NAME**".equals(packname)) {
                startActivity(pwdIntent);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use sharedPref.getString function

Comment: Thank you for your kind response Mtetno, But can you please tell me that how to use this and where to use this. I mean, can I use it in this peace of code??

Comment: Use List instead of using StringBuilder

Comment: @Devraj just paste this `SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), MODE_PRIVATE);` which will declared ur shared pref and hence ur string will be `String myPackage=prefs.getString("urKey",null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above question

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(getPackageName() , MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.getstring("key");
```

will give your saved string from SharedPreferences where ever you want in Application.

If you like you can go through other solution given as below for optimization

```
 public void addTask(Task t) {
            if (null == currentTasks) {
                currentTasks = new ArrayList<task>();
            }
            currentTasks.add(t);

            //save the task list to preference
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            try {
                editor.putString(TASKS, ObjectSerializer.serialize(currentTasks));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            editor.commit();
        }
```

Similarly we can retrieve the list of tasks from the preference inside onCreate() method:

```
  public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            if (null == currentTasks) {
                currentTasks = new ArrayList<task>();
            }

            //      load tasks from preference
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            try {
                currentTasks = (ArrayList<task>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(prefs.getString(TASKS, ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList<task>())));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```